Poetry can't install setuptools?
I'm trying to use Poetry to run jenkins-job-builder 4.3 (yes it's old but IIUC upgrading is non-trivial). However, it fails with:
ERROR:stevedore.extension:Could not load '<command>': No module named 'pkg_resources'

This seems to indicate that I need setuptools, and indeed on machines where pythonX/site-packages/pkg_resources exists, it seems to be owned by setuptools. Here, however, is where I run into problems.
If I add this to pyproject.toml:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
setuptools = "*"

I get:
Because <project> depends on setuptools (*) which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.

(Same results with anything else I've tried for the version specification.)
This is all in a GHA runner using Python 3.12 and Poetry 1.8.2 (installed via Python 3.10.12). My local machine (using Python 3.10) is able to run jenkins-jobs just fine. Also, setuptools and pkg_resources exist in my local Poetry cache. So it seems "install setuptools" is the correct solution... except I can't figure out how to do that. It either does it on its own without being told, or refuses to do it at all.
How do I convince Poetry to reliably install setuptools?

In case it's useful, my GHA script looks like:
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: ubuntu:latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "$HOME/.local/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
          apt-get -qq update
          apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install pipx
      - run: pipx install poetry
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'
          cache: poetry
      - run: poetry install

Also, in one experiment, I managed to get:
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 69.5.1 (/github/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/.../lib/python3.10/site-packages), Requirement.parse('setuptools<=65.7.0'))

...which is from jenkins_job_builder-4.3.0.dist-info/METADATA.

Have to you tried using a specific version of setuptools in your pyproject.toml? pip install setuptools in your activated venv? Or alternatively poetry add --group dev setuptools? In Python 3.12 , PEP 632 removed the distutils package, in favor of using setuptools. Additionally, CPython Github issue 95299 was resolved, so that the bundled setuptools is no longer installed in environments created with venv

@nigh_anxiety, "[I get the] same results with anything else I've tried for the version specification". In case that was unclear, yes, that includes specific versions. I don't have an "activated venv"; that's the whole point of using Poetry! poetry add --group complains that The "--group" option does not exist..

@nigh_anxiety, I guess you meant poetry add --dev setuptools (locally I have Poetry 1.1.12). That just gives the same "setuptools (^69.5.1) ... doesn't match any versions" error.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
